# Scala script to copy files

Tags: scala, file, copy

I want to copy file a.txt to newDir/ from within a scala script. 
In java this would be done by creating 2 file streams for the 2 files, reading into buffer from a.txt and writing it to the FileOutputStream of the new file. 
Is there a better way to achieve this in scala? May be something in scala.tools.nsc.io._. I searched around but could not find much.

Comment: The [os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) project is by far the best modern solution.  It's performant and hides unnecessary complexity.  See my answer for a code snippet.

Answer (score 37):

For performance reasons it is better to use *java.nio.Channel* to do the copying.

Listing of **copy.scala**:

```
import java.io.{File,FileInputStream,FileOutputStream}
val src = new File(args(0))
val dest = new File(args(1))
new FileOutputStream(dest) getChannel() transferFrom(
    new FileInputStream(src) getChannel, 0, Long.MaxValue )
```

To try this out create a file called **test.txt** with the following content:

```
Hello World
```

After creating **test.txt**, run the following from the command line:

```
scala copy.scala test.txt test-copy.txt
```

Verify that **test-copy.txt** has `Hello World` as its content.

Comment: A side-benefit of my solution is that it supports binary files.

A side-effect is that it ties you to Java, which is bad if you intend to run your Scala code on .NET.

Comment: That's also much nicer code than dealing with the bytes yourself.

Comment: This is a great answer and should be the accepted solution IMO. One thing to note, you may need to call `dest.createNewFile` as the FileInputStream will fail if dest does not exist. Also, you may need `dest.getCanonicalFile.getParentFile.mkdirs` to create any parent directories of the dest file.

Comment: Can you cancel the transfer from another actor? (suppose it is a long transfer and the user decides to abort)

Comment: @Mahdi yes indeed. **FileChannel** is an **InterruptibleChannel** which supports operation cancellation via **close()** on either source or destination channel and via **Thread#interrupt()**.  You could call **Thread#interrupt()** on the actor's thread somehow, but it's more intent-revealing to retain a reference to the source channel and call **close()** on it to halt the transfer.

Answer (score 36):

Why not use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io) and [FileUtils.copyFile()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)) in particular ? Note that FileUtils has a large number of methods to copy files/directories etc.

Comment: Downvoted why ? Reuse of an existing component for this seems pragmatic to me.

Comment: I can think of a couple reasons: it's not idiomatic Scala, the link is broken, and it introduces a 181 KB dependency on your project for something that could be written in fewer than 10 lines of code (admittedly that one's debatable).  But most prominently the answer below demonstrates how to accomplish this with built-in java.nio.

Comment: Link fixed. As for introducing a 181Kb dependency, I wouldn't really worry. Besides, it's quite likely that either you're using such libs already, and I'd definitely investigate such libraries for utilities like this, rather than put together your own 'utility' library doing something similar

Comment: Introducing 3rd party dependencies is okay so long as you're building the final product. If you're shipping your code to be run inside another app, you'd be introducing transitive dependencies which is not a good idea, particularly for something as simple as this.

Answer (score 23):

Java 7 is now out and you have another option: `java.nio.file.Files.copy`. The probably easiest solution (And with Scalas superior `import` even easier). Provided that `from` and `to` are strings as in your question:

```
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING
import java.nio.file.Files.copy
import java.nio.file.Paths.get

implicit def toPath (filename: String) = get(filename)

copy (from, to, REPLACE_EXISTING)
```

Of course you should start using `java.nio.file.Paths` instead of strings.

Answer (score 12):

If you really want to do it yourself instead of using a library like commons-io, you can do the following in version 2.8. Create a helper method "use". It will give you a form of automatic resource management.

```
def use[T <: { def close(): Unit }](closable: T)(block: T => Unit) {
  try {
    block(closable)
  }
  finally {
    closable.close()
  }
}
```

Then you can define a copy method like this:

```
import java.io._

@throws(classOf[IOException])
def copy(from: String, to: String) {
  use(new FileInputStream(from)) { in =>
    use(new FileOutputStream(to)) { out =>
      val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
      Iterator.continually(in.read(buffer))
          .takeWhile(_ != -1)
          .foreach { out.write(buffer, 0 , _) }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the buffer size (here: 1024) might need some tuning.

Comment: IMO, the nio.Channel solution is much simpler

Comment: The nio is indeed simpler, but this snippet is so cool! Classic Scala.

Answer (score 5):

Hire **sbt.IO**. It's pure scala, it can copy only changed files, has usefull routines like `copyDirectory`, `delete`, `listFiles` etc . You can use it as follow:

```
import sbt._
IO.copyFile(file1, file2)
```

Note you should add proper dependency:

`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" % "io" % "0.13.0"`

**EDIT**:
Actually this is not a good approach since dependency `"org.scala-sbt" % "io" % "version"`  was compiled using particular scala version and for now you cannot use it with 2.10.X scala version. But maybe in future you will can add double %% in you dependency like `"org.scala-sbt" %% "io" % "version"` and it will work...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care too much about speed, you can make your life slightly easier by reading the file using scala.io.Source (this implementation is for 2.7.7):

```
def copyF(from: java.io.File, to: String) {
  val out = new java.io.BufferedWriter( new java.io.FileWriter(to) );
  io.Source.fromFile(from).getLines.foreach(s => out.write(s,0,s.length));
  out.close()
}
```

But Source goes to all the trouble of parsing the file line by line, and then you just write it out again without actually processing the lines.  Using byte read/write Java style will be considerably faster (about 2-3x last time I benchmarked it).

---

Edit: 2.8 eats newlines, so you have to add them back in the write.

Comment: I might have large number of files and different types of files to copy. The files can also quite big in size. Would slurp() or any other apis in the scalax help?

Comment: In that case, I'd say Brian's suggestion is the right one--use the Apache Commons IO.  It's made to do just what you want, and Scala is made to use Java libraries.

Comment: @aioobe - This answer was for 2.7.7, as I stated.  2.8 eats newlines.  You also have to add `()` after getLines in 2.8.

Comment: Ah, didn't know they changed the implementation!  Changed to +1

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot delete destination file after your copy. Surely, we must make it accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [os-lib](https://github.com/lihaoyi/os-lib) project makes it easy to copy a file in Scala:

```scala
os.copy(
  os.pwd/"src"/"test"/"resources"/"a_file.csv",
  os.pwd/"newDir"/"a_file.csv"
)
```

The library uses `java.nio` and `java.io` underneath the hood, but hides all the messiness from end users.  It's the easiest modern way to perform filesystem operations, by far.  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/filesystem-paths-move-copy-list-delete-folders/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use anything external, just do it as you would have done it in Java. The nice thing, is that you can.

Answer (score 0):

[Scalax](http://scalax.scalaforge.org/) has scalax.io.FileExtras.copyTo(dest : File). But developement seems to have stopped.

Answer (score -1):

From [scala-io documentation](http://jesseeichar.github.io/scala-io-doc/0.4.2/index.html#!/core/copy_to):

```
import scalax.io._
import Resource._

fromFile("a.txt") copyDataTo fromFile("newDir/a.txt")
```

Comment: scala-io looks like a dead project