# Fast Mass File Copying in Scala with Akka

Tags: scala, nio, actor, akka

I am wondering what would be the best way to Copy a file src to dest within Scala that will be wrapped in an Akka Actor and possibly using a RemoteActor with several machines.

I have a tremendous amount of image files I have to copy from one directory to a NFS mounted directory.

Haven't done much FileHandling in Java or Scala, but know there is the NIO lib and some others out there that have been worked on since Scala 2.7. Something that would be the safest and quickest.

I probably should give some idea of my infrastructure as well. The connection is 1000 MB's in which connects via a Cisco3560 from an Isilon node to a Windows 2003 Server. The Isilon node is the NFS mount and the Windows 2003 Server is a highly configured Samba(Cifs) mount.

Comment: Just curious, why don't you copy them using OS tools, as usually?

Comment: We're talking Terabytes of Image data that has to be copied and converted. By Terabytes it's 97TB to be exact. Plus the time it needs to be done is of course yesterday as with most things. :(

Comment: Still not enough information--where is the data now?  Multiple disks, each independently addressable?  And you want to put it onto the NFS server?  Even at 1000 MB/s, if you can manage it, it'll take you over a day for 97 TB.  Why can't you just open up multiple shell windows and run a bunch of copy commands simultaneously?

Comment: ahh sorry Rex, It's because there is some conversions on the files, plus something that is happening is a new directory structure change and some files that are older will be ignored based on other credentials such as how popular the image is based on some db transactions. I have an application already written in Scala to handle everything else. I just wanted to wrap it up in an Akka Remote Actor and take advantage of multiple machines to handle all the other transactions. I'm more worried about the actual copying part. Just trying out Apache Commons IO for now and seeing if it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't beat the underlying OS file copy speed, so if the files are large or you can batch them, you're probably best off writing a shell script with Scala and then calling it with bash or somesuch.  Chances are that one thread can saturate the disk IO, so there really isn't anything fancy to do.  If the images are large, you'll be waiting for the 50ish MB/s limit on your disk (or 10ish MB/s limit on your 100 Mbps ethernet); if they're small, you'll be waiting for the quite-some-dozens of ms overhead on file seeks and network ping times and so on.

That said, you can use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/), which has a file copy utility, and a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225214) has a high-performance answer among the top rated entries.  You can have one actor handle all the copying tasks, and that should be as fast as if you have a bunch of actors all trying to compete for the same limited IO bandwidth.

Comment: I'm currently copying everything via a Python script and it works great it's just a bit slow and I thought I could take advantage of several 16 core machines to do RemoteActors or some sort of Remote Message Queuing for a lot faster file copying.