# Simple Java/Scala file copy that takes buffer/buffer size as parameter

Tags: java, scala, file, copy, buffer

I'm looking for a simple java copy file function that takes a buffer size. I've tried java.nio.Files, whose copy method doesn't take a buffer size, neither does apache commons FileUtils.copyFile. Am I missing something, or do I really need to hand-roll something here?

Comment: this is not how SO works, show us what you tried

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream)

Curiously enough, as I mentioned in my OP, neither of them take a buffer size argument.

https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=java+scala+file+copy+specify+buffer+size&oq=java+scala+file+copy+specify+buffer+size&aqs=chrome..69i57.8903j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Also yielded nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala script to copy files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225214/scala-script-to-copy-files). The answers there have options to pass buffer sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Scala has a good io library, you can use it to read(buffered by default).
For writing java has `BufferedWriter`, you can use it to write

```
import scala.io._
import java.io._

val input = Source.fromFile(new File("foo.txt"), 1000)

val outputFile = new File("bar.txt")
val output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile), 1000)

input.foreach { char => 
  output.write(char)
}
output.flush()
```

Yeap, you just copied foo.txt to bar.txt

Comment: And BufferedWriter takes a buffer-size parameter, should the OP need to set the size explicitly.